# Chain rule for scalar-matrix differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $u:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{J \times N}$ and $G: \mathbb{R}^{J \times N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{J \times M}$ with $M \leq N$, how would one write down the chain rule for the expression 
$$\frac{d}{dt} G(u(t))$$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand into the first order in $\tau$ the expression $G(u(t+\tau))$.
You have 
$$G(u(t+\tau))=G\left(u(t)+\tau\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}(t)+o(\tau)\right).$$
You know that $\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}(t)$ is in $\mathbb R^{J\times N}$. Now use the same expression with $G(a+\tau b)=G(a)+\tau b\cdot \mathrm dG+o(\tau)$
and you're done.

*EDIT*

If you want something more specific with coordinates, you have
$$\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\mathrm du_{ij}}{\mathrm dt}\end{bmatrix}$$
and $$(\mathrm dG)_{ijk\ell}=\frac{\partial G_{k\ell}}{\partial u_{ij}}$$ such that 
$$(b\cdot \mathrm dG)_{k\ell}=\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial G_{k\ell}}{\partial u_{ij}}b_{ij}$$

Comment: I don't see how writing down the first order Taylor series of $u$ and $G$ helps me?

Comment: I guess my question is a lot more general than I thought. Based on your expansion we should end up with $\frac{du}{dt} dG(u)$ meaning $dG : \mathbb{R}^{J \times N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$. I more wondering what properties this operator has? How is it even defined? I can't find anything on Google about functions of non-square matrices.